# How to add non generic method to wrap generic method

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, generics, razor

ASP.NET MVC4 razor helper cannot pass type parameters to generic methods. To fix this, probably best way is to add non-generic get method with signature

```
public static string Get(Type entityType)
```

How to add this wrapper so it calls generic Get method in this class. Should reflection used or is there better way?

```
 [AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Class | AttributeTargets.Method)]
  public sealed class LocalizableDisplayNameAttributeI :   DisplayNameAttribute
   {

    public LocalizableDisplayNameAttributeI(string displayName) : base(displayName) { }

    public override string DisplayName
    {
        get
        {
            return global::Res.Translate(base.DisplayName);
        }
    }

    public static string Get<TEntity>()
    {
        foreach (LocalizableDisplayNameAttributeI attrib in
            typeof(TEntity).GetCustomAttributes(typeof(LocalizableDisplayNameAttributeI), true))
        {
            return attrib.DisplayName;
        }
        return typeof(TEntity).Name;
}}
```

Comment: In my test MVC 4 helper, I could pass type parameters to generic methods.  What kind of errors are you getting?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do that using reflection as @JeppeStigNielsen already indicated.

```
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Class | AttributeTargets.Method)]
public sealed class LocalizableDisplayNameAttributeI : DisplayNameAttribute
{
    private static readonly MethodInfo _getMethod = typeof(LocalizableDisplayNameAttributeI)
        .GetMethods().First(x => x.IsGenericMethod && x.Name == "Get");

    public LocalizableDisplayNameAttributeI(string displayName) : base(displayName) { }

    public override string DisplayName
    {
        get
        {
            return global::Res.Translate(base.DisplayName);
        }
    }

    public static string Get(Type entityType)
    {
        return (string)_getMethod.MakeGenericMethod(entityType).Invoke(null, null);
    }

    public static string Get<TEntity>()
    {
        var attrib = typeof(TEntity)
            .GetCustomAttributes(typeof(LocalizableDisplayNameAttributeI), true)
            .FirstOrDefault() as LocalizableDisplayNameAttributeI;
        return attrib != null ? attrib.DisplayName : typeof(TEntity).Name;
    }
}
```

But it seems you don't really need this, because you are not using the template argument.

**You can simply do:**

```
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Class | AttributeTargets.Method)]
public sealed class LocalizableDisplayNameAttributeI : DisplayNameAttribute
{
    public LocalizableDisplayNameAttributeI(string displayName) : base(displayName) { }

    public override string DisplayName
    {
        get
        {
            return global::Res.Translate(base.DisplayName);
        }
    }

    public static string Get(Type entityType)
    {
        var attrib = entityType
            .GetCustomAttributes(typeof(LocalizableDisplayNameAttributeI), true)
            .FirstOrDefault() as LocalizableDisplayNameAttributeI;
        return attrib != null ? attrib.DisplayName : entityType.Name;
    }

    public static string Get<TEntity>()
    {
        return Get(typeof(TEntity));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Reflection.

```
return (string)(
    typeof(LocalizableDisplayNameAttributeI)
    .GetMethod("Get")
    .MakeGenericMethod(entityType)
    .Invoke(null, null)
    );
```

This answer only relates to how to call a generic method. However in the actual case, it is much easier to just write the method again in a non-generic version. Because you only use `TEntity` in the context `typeof(TEntity)`. Therefore you could simply search-and-replace `typeof(TEntity)` by `entityType` to get your non-generic version of the method.

Comment: Almost, still needs `BindingFlags.Static` for static method.

Comment: @Alex Wrong. The overload I use (where I do not give the binding flags) actually uses `private const BindingFlags DefaultLookup = BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.Static | BindingFlags.Public;` as its binding flags. As you see `BindingFlags.Static` is set.

Comment: I stand corrected, I did not know the default included static.

Answer (score 1):

Going from a `Type` to a generic call is a pain, but going from a generic call to a `Type` is easy.  Can you swap your wrapper order?

```
public static string Get<TEntity>()
{
    return Get(typeof(TEntity));
}

public static string Get(Type entityType)
{
    foreach (LocalizableDisplayNameAttributeI attrib in
        entityType.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(LocalizableDisplayNameAttributeI), true))
    {
        return attrib.DisplayName;
    }
    return entityType.Name;
}
```